# Ventanas alerta con javascipt al hacer log in

Tags: javascript, html, login, validación

Quiero validar que los campos estén llenos con js pero no me funciona el mensaje de alerta

```js
function loginadmin() {

  if (document.getElementsById('name_admin').value; == '') {
    alert("[ERROR] Favor de ingresar Usuario");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="js/loginadmin.js"></script>
<form action="php/login_admin.php" method="post" onsubmit="return loginadmin()">
  <label class="label-name" for="name_admin"><b>Nombre de usuario:</b></label><br>
  <!-- El label me muestra el nombre por encima de la caja de texto-->
  <input type="text" id="name_admin" name="name_admin" class="data"><br>
  <!--placeholder: es para sombra sobre la caja-->
  <!--El input es la entrada de datos a la pagina el nombre es la manarea de linkear y reconocer el texto ingresado-->
  <label class="label-name" for="pass_admin"><b>Contraseña:</b></label><br>
  <input type="password" id="pass_admin" name="pass_admin" class="data"><br><br><br>
  <input type="submit" class="main_button" name="submint" value="Iniciar Sesion"><br><br>
</form>
```

Alguien que me pueda ayudar, ya intente acomodarlo de varias formas e incluso lo intente hacer por php sin embargo tampoco me permite llamo el 
echo y adentro el alert y tampoco funciona

Comment: Tienes que quitar el submit. La funcion `type=submit` hace que tu pagina cambie al momento a `php/login_admin.php`. Y en ese mismo boton pon un `onclick=loginAdmin()` y veras como funciona.

Comment: Intenta cambiando a getElementById (singular) y retirando el punto y come de la siguiente linea: **document.getElementById('hola').value == ''**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

es get `getElementById` no `getElementsById` por eso no funciona

Answer (score 0):

Lo más eficiente para validar que los campos estén llenos no es en JavaScript (que por supuesto que se puede) sino directamente en el input del html, que debería ser algo parecido a:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el required no dejará que avance sin rellenar el input, le aparecerá una alerta sobre el campo requerido para guiar al usuario. A demás por tema de facilitar al usuario que solucione el error que ha cometido, es conveniente no lanzar alertas de JavaScript.

Comment: Hola se te agradece el apoyo, sin embargo te recomiendo que el código vaya como texto y no como imagen, puedes leer  [answer]

Comment: Gracias pero eso no es una buena manera de seguridad ya que si pones "required" puedes abrir el inspector borrar el "required" y te deja enviar el formulario realmente el "required" es sencillo pero no es una buena manera de seguridad.

Comment: Pero eso lo podrá hacer siempre el cliente, el caso es meter todo los validadores de nuevo en servidor, que es donde no puede tocar el usuario, recuerdo que esto es para guiar a quien lo necesite y que envíe la información correctamente pero cualquiera te puede partir la página y liartela en servidor, para eso se vuelve a ver los campos de nuevo donde no puede tocar nadie